# What lambda function optimizations, if any, are planned for Java 9 and beyond?

Tags: java, functional-programming, optimization, lambda, java8

I'm working on a high-performance project where Java 8's lambda functions are enormously useful. I've found, however, that they're memory inefficient when used en masse. For example, suppose I need to apply a lambda function 1,000,000 times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i += 1) {
  collection.forEach(thing -> thing.foo());
}
```

In this form, `thing -> thing.foo()` *seems* to instantiate 1,000,000 objects, which has nasty speed ramifications when done repeatedly. My standard optimization, where necessary, has been to do the following refactoring:

```
Consumer<Thing> DoFoo = thing -> thing.foo(); 
for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i += 1) {
  collection.forEach(DoFoo);
}
```

This removes the memory overhead and is trivial to do. This brings me to my question: if something so simple results in such big performance gains, why doesn't the Java compiler perform this refactoring for me? Are there other optimizations that could be made such that lambda performance/overhead is more predictable and efficient? If so, are they planned for release in future versions? Lambdas have proven wonderfully effective, but when I need to worry about low-level stuff when using them, it degrades the usefulness of their abstraction.

Comment: That example is rather contrived. It's more natural to either use two loops or two high-order functions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we aren't the Java developers and can't be an authoritative source on their future plan.

Comment: How did you determine that `thing -> thing.foo()` gets instantiated on each pass? I tried writing a loop where each iteration ran `System.out.println((Supplier<Object>) (() -> new Object()));` twice, and I found that each iteration printed the same two instances. (As in, it appeared that each *lexical* occurrence of `() -> new Object()` resulted in only one lambda object being instantiated.) See http://ideone.com/4O0qqE. *[continued]*

Comment: *[continued]* So I wonder if the compiler is smart enough to do this optimization in cases where it can prove that it's safe, but that your *real* code is, for some reason, a situation where it's not provably a safe transformation.

Comment: @Ixrec Some members might be. Or there might have been a draft spec. Perhaps there's a technical reason why this can't be done. I think it should stay open.

Comment: Dylan: can you share some actual numbers? Like @ruakh said, I'd be interested too how you "deduced" that a million more objects have been instantiated.

Comment: I tested it too and I obtain almost identical results for the example above. http://ideone.com/x3Ec7I

Comment: @ruakh - you can't be sure that those apparently identical instances are not actually different.  Presumably you're comparing them based on the system hash code, but that is only guaranteed valid as long as the object is still live.  If it becomes unreachable, the hash code can be reused.  Java's garbage collector is often smart enough to realise that this has been done and collect the object immediately after it has been finished with, which would make the code available for reuse immediately.

Comment: @Jules: That's a good point. To address it, I've now edited the program to keep all instances alive (by using them as keys in a `IdentityHashMap`), and still see how many distinct instances there are (by printing out the `IdentityHashMap` at the end). As expected, it still shows that there are only two instances: http://ideone.com/4O0qqE.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone! I understand the example is contrived: it is a simplified example of what I encounter. The one million figure was inferred because (a) there are enormous memory spikes when similar production code is run and (b) these spikes disappear when the lambda is stored in a variable (as per the example optimization). The million figure is likely inaccurate, but something very inefficient is clearly occurring in my code. If it's not reproducible with the example, then I suspect it's something specific to my situation and as such not useful here. Feel free to close! :)

Comment: @dylanknowles If you search YouTube for `brian goetz java` you'll find useful and interesting talks from Java's main architect about the design of lambdas (note the number of decisions where he points out that doing the obvious thing would suck), the optimizations left for after Java 8, and stuff coming in Java 9.

Comment: "why doesn't the Java compiler perform this refactoring for me?" Many programmers don't know that the Java Language and VM specs promise "precise exceptions." This helps portability tremendously but it severely limits optimizations like loop unrolling since an exception raised in code moved by the optimizers wouldn't occur at the right time. In theory the compiler + VM could make the exception look like it occurred at the right time, but only if it could roll back all intervening side effects.

Comment: I am not a Java developer and even less can speak for them. I also understand that your example is somewhat contrived but you tried to pick one representative of your concern. An issue when we reason about languages, compilers, etc, and we wish they'd be more optimizing is we tend to forget important notions like program equivalence. It is easy for our super computer brain to always see the big picture, but it isn't for a compiler bound to strict rules such as lexical scope, etc. In your example the 2 lambdas are captured differently: for a compiler the 2 code snippets are just not equivalent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we aren't the Java developers and can't be an authoritative source on their future plan

Comment: I disagree with the close votes since one could read the mailing lists and there are presentations on the subject matter given and hell you could even email people at Oracle so there are valid definitive sources for information.

Comment: I can't see why this would allocate a new lambda object for each iteration. It doesn't close over anything in scope of the loop, *nor* does it close over anything. I doubt it doesn't do this already.